# Wierd combination

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, combinations

I have an array of 3 integers `{1,2,3}`. I need to print combinations in the form of-

```
1 1+2 1+3 1+2+3

2 2+3

3
```

```
for(int i = 0; i < array.size(); ++i)
{ 
    for(int j = 0; (i + j) < array.size(); ++j)
    {
        sum += my[i + j];
        cout << sum << " ";
        c++;                            
    } 
    cout << endl;
}
```

In above, `1+3` is being skipped.

Please help me with that.

Comment: What did you do till now?

Answer (score 0):

Given a set S the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) P(S) is the set of all subsets of S.  What you are trying to do is essentially enumerate all of the non-empty elements of x ∈ P(S).  From there, you can iterate over all of the elements of each non-empty x in P(S).

What does this mean for you?  Well for starters for a set S containing n elements the number of possible elements of P(S) is 2^n, so the size of the power set scales exponentially with the size of its generating set.

But, where this may be useful for small values of n (in particular n < 64) you can use `unsigned long long` variables to act as a kind of index.  In particular, each bit corresponds to one of your array elements.  Bits with a value of 0 exclude its associated element in the sum, while bits with a 1 would include the element.  To do something like this try the following:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

void print_sum(const std::vector<int>& array, unsigned long long i) { 
    int sum = 0;

    for (int index=0; i > 0; i=i>>1, ++index) {
        if (i % 2 == 1) {
            std::cout << array[index] << (i>1 ? "+" : "=");
            sum += array[index];
        }
    }
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
}

void printer(const std::vector<int>& array) {
    if (array.size() < sizeof(unsigned long long) * 8) {
        unsigned long long n = 1 << array.size();
        for (unsigned long long i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
            print_sum(array, i);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::vector<int> sample {1, 2, 3, 4};

    printer(sample);

    return 0;
}
```

This program has output:

```
1=1
2=2
1+2=3
3=3
1+3=4
2+3=5
1+2+3=6
4=4
1+4=5
2+4=6
1+2+4=7
3+4=7
1+3+4=8
2+3+4=9
1+2+3+4=10
```